# Slide over navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I've been trying to create a 'Slide over navigation bar' The idea is I would like this to slide over 100% width of the page with an opacity set to around 0.7 and for the 2 line burger bar to transform to a cross.

I've managed to create the burger bar and get it to transform. I cannot when I click this I cannot get it to close the nav slide! It also comes from the left and would like this to come from the right!

I'm not skilled enough yet to understand how JavaScript works fully and if this is interfering with the open-close functions. Also, I'm not sure what I've recently done but it just seems to completely disappear now!

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
let menuOpen = false;
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!menuOpen) {
    menuBtn.classList.add('open');
    menuOpen = true;
  } else {
    menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
    menuOpen = false;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.menu-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 95%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu-btn-burger::before,
.menu-btn-burger::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-btn-burger::after {
  transform: translateY(16px);
}

.menu-btn.open .menu-btn-burger::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.menu-btn.open .menu-btn-burger::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.logobrand {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9%;
  left: 4%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.btn a {
  padding: 5px;
}

.btn {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  right: 10%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: white;
}

.work {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.7;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.listitems {
  position: absolute;
  left: 70%;
  top: 30%;
}

.side-nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 1s;
  transform: translateX(99%);
}

.side-nav a {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  list-style: none;
}

.side-nav a:hover {
  color: silver;
}

.side-nav .btn-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
}

a li {
  width: 220px;
}

.instagram {
  height: 35px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.facebook {
  height: 35px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.twitter {
  height: 35px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.linkedin {
  height: 35px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.social {
  position: absolute;
  top: 95%;
  left: 88%;
  display: block;
}

.copy {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Montserrat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" />

<video class="work" autoplay loop muted src="img/Video.mov"></video>
<nav class="navbar">
  <span class="open-slide">
      <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
          <div class="menu-btn" onclick="show()">
              <div class="menu-btn-burger"></div>
          </div>
      </a>
  </span>
</nav>
<a class="btn" href="#">
  <h3>Request a Quote</h3>
</a>
<div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
  <a href="#" class="btn-close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">
    <div class="menu-btn" onclick="show()">
      <div class="menu-btn-burger"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="listitems">
      <a href="#">
        <li>Who we are</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>What we offer</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>How can we help?</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Chat to us</li>
      </a>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="logo"><img class="logobrand" src="img/Chatting Creative logo.png" alt=""></div>

<div class="social">
  <img class="instagram" src="img/1t.png" alt="">
  <img class="facebook" src="img/2t.png" alt="">
  <img class="twitter" src="img/3t.png" alt="">
  <img class="linkedin" src="img/4t.png" alt="">
</div>

<footer>
  <p class="copy">
    &copy; Chatting Creative 2020
  </p>
</footer>

<script>
  function openSlideMenu() {
    document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '100%';
    document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '250px';
  }

  function closeSlideMenu() {
    document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0px';
    document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '0px';
  }
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script>
  AOS.init();
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please reduce the example to a _working_ [mcve] (remove anything that is not directly related to the problem).

Comment: It's invalid to have other action elements inside `<a>` anchors.

Comment: It's invalid markup to place `<div>` inside `<span>` and it's also invalid to have `<li>` elements inside `<a>` . LIs parent should be UL or OL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two examples, one using HTML+CSS and one using JavaScript

## Using a checkbox

You could use a hidden checkbox instead of JS.
See this example and find the comments in code.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 200vh;   /* JUST FOR DEMO - remove this afterwards. */
  border: 4px dashed #000;
}

#btn-burger { /* Use ID. You need only one of these */
  position: fixed; /* make it fixed */
  z-index: 2;
  top: 25px;
  right: 25px; /* use right */
  width: 30px; /* should be 30, not 40 */
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#btn-burger::before,
#btn-burger::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
#btn-burger::after { transform: translateY(16px); }

#side-menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  /* Do not use width 0 */
  top: 0;
  right: 0;    /* Use right 0 */
  background-color: #ddd;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 1s;
  transform: translateX(100%); /* Use 100% */
}

#side-menu a {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  display: block;
}

#menuHandler:checked ~ #btn-burger::before { transform: rotate(45deg); }
#menuHandler:checked ~ #btn-burger::after  { transform: rotate(-45deg); }
#menuHandler:checked ~ #side-menu { transform: translateX(0%); } /* do not use width here */
```

```html
<input id="menuHandler" type="checkbox" hidden />

<label id="btn-burger" for="menuHandler"></label>

<div id="side-menu">
  <ul class="listItems">
    <li><a href="#">Who we are</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">What we offer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">How can we help?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Chat to us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Additionally remember:

- It's invalid to have other action elements inside `<a>` anchors.
- It's invalid markup to place `<div>` inside `<span>`
- It's also invalid to have `<li>` elements inside `<a>` . `LI`s parent should be `<ul>` or `<ol>`

## Example using JavaScript

On click you can simply perform a [`Element.classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
const EL_burger = document.querySelector("#btn-burger");
const EL_menu = document.querySelector("#side-menu");
const EL_listItems = EL_menu.querySelectorAll("a");

const toggleSideMenu = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  EL_menu.classList.toggle('is-open');
  EL_burger.classList.toggle('is-open');
}

EL_burger.addEventListener('click', toggleSideMenu);

// If your're building a singlePage app than you'll also need this:
EL_listItems.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', toggleSideMenu));
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 200vh;   /* JUST FOR DEMO - remove this afterwards. */
  border: 4px dashed #000;
}

#btn-burger { /* Use ID. You need only one of these */
  position: fixed; /* make it fixed */
  z-index: 2;
  top: 25px;
  right: 25px; /* use right */
  width: 30px; /* should be 30, not 40 */
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#btn-burger::before,
#btn-burger::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
#btn-burger::after { transform: translateY(16px); }

#side-menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  /* Do not use width 0 */
  top: 0;
  right: 0;    /* Use right 0 */
  background-color: #ddd;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 1s;
  transform: translateX(100%); /* Use 100% */
}

#side-menu a {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  display: block;
}

#btn-burger.is-open::before { transform: rotate(45deg); }
#btn-burger.is-open::after  { transform: rotate(-45deg); }
#side-menu.is-open { transform: translateX(0%); } /* do not use width here */
```

```html
<a id="btn-burger"></a>

<div id="side-menu">
  <ul class="listItems">
    <li><a href="#">Who we are</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">What we offer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">How can we help?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Chat to us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably the better canonical answer +1

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it looks like you tried to implement at least three different ways of solving this problem. I suggest you start over with the core functionality. Below you find a possible approach. I tried to stay close to your code.

There are many ways of achieving the effect you want. I used HTML-classes which are toggled `on` and `off` via `Element.classList.toggle('class')` with each click on the `menuBtn`. All styling changes are then applied by the CSS because it is defined there that `#side-menu.open` has slightly different styling than `#side-menu` (same without `open`-class).

```js
const menuBtn = document.getElementById('menu-btn');
const menuItems = document.getElementById('side-menu');

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menuBtn.classList.toggle("open");
  menuItems.classList.toggle("open");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#menu-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 15px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}

#menu-btn:before,
#menu-btn:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu-btn:after {
  transform: translateY(16px);
}

#menu-btn.open:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #fff;
}

#menu-btn.open:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: #fff;
}

#side-menu {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: .4s;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#side-menu.open {
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
}

#side-menu a {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#side-menu.open a {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .1s;
}

#side-menu a:hover {
  color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-btn"></div>
<div id="side-menu">
  <a href="#">
    <li>Who we are</li>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <li>What we offer</li>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <li>How can we help?</li>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <li>Chat to us</li>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Really grateful thank you, this works perfectly. I agree my code is all over the place I've been learning from scratch for about 2 months so apologies for the mess and for all the extra info that wasn't needed! Best Connor

Comment: @ConnorChatt Glad, it helped! Sometimes it's best to start over instead of fighting your own old code ^^

Answer (score -1):

For starters: You can toggle classes (add/remove) without keeping state, check out the examples here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

```
menuBtn.classList.toggle('open')
```

See if that fixes your issue and brush up on how variable scoping works:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Generally speaking, the community prefers questions that could help others in the future, and this is very specific to the issue that you're encountering. Either way, good luck and welcome to StackOverflow :)